# Pass 2d array in get method

Tags: spring-boot, restful-url, get-mapping

I have to pass a 2d integer array to get REST call.

> Example:[[1,2,3], [5,10,11]]

I can pass it by entering data separately into the parameter like

> Example: http://localhost:1136/demo?x=3,4,5&x=10,11,12

But I want it to be like

> ?x=[[1,2,3], [5,10,11]]

Any suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You can define a **`@RequestParam(value= "x") String[][]`** like this:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/demo")
public void demo(@RequestParam(value= "x") String[][] array2d) {
    // You will get: array2d = [[3,4,5],[10,11,12]]
}
```

---

**Note:** You may get the valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986 error.

You can add to `application.properties` file something like this:

```yaml
tomcat.relaxed-query-chars="|,{,},[,]"
```

Comment: I defined it in the same way. But unable to pass in request call as I mentioned above.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request-target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986

Comment: Do you want to send a request `../demo?x = [[1,2,3], [5,10,11]]`?

Comment: yes. Similar to the above or ?x={ {1,2,3}, {5,10,11} }

Comment: I added the error that will fix your `The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986` error as a note. It will be quick and easy to run your request as in the example. If you do not have the possibility to do this and **you will need to obtain the value with `@RequestParam (value =" x ") String array2d` and process it manually.**

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. I have added these properties to the application.properties file.

server.tomcat.relaxed-path-chars=[, ]
server.tomcat.relaxed-query-chars=[, ]